# Can you restrict the payee and amount of a blank check?

Tags: check, checking-account

Suppose I want to allow John Smith to spend up to $30 out of my checking account at McDonald's at any point in the future (but only one time). If I write a check payable to McDonald's and sign it, but write on the memo line "For use only by John Smith (please check ID) with an amount not to exceed thirty dollars", would that accomplish what I want? What risks would there be?

Comment: Which country? In the US, what you write on the memo line has zero effect on your check. It is a _memo_ to yourself.

Comment: Yes, in the US.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? (other than giving John Smith a $30 McDonald's gift card, which would accomplish the limits on where to spend it and how much, but wouldn't stop John from giving/selling the card to someone else)

Comment: @Flux yes, thank you!

Comment: I suspect the person receiving the cheque is going to be under no obligation to follow any special instructions on the cheque.